# Docker GUI app (xterm window) from VNC host

Tags: docker, vnc, xterm

I've built a very basic docker container to try and proof of concept running an xterm window from inside it.

In it, I have a basic install of RHEL 7.3 and xterm

I build as normal, open xhost `xhost +` and then run the docker run command like so:

```
docker run -ti --rm -e DISPLAY=${DISPLAY} -v /tmp/.X11-unix:/tmp.X11-unix xtermDemo /bin/bash
```

This runs perfectly when my base host is linux. The problem is that most of the developers in my organization run with a Windows/Mac host and log into a VNC session. When running the docker image from the VNC session xterm can’t run.

Any ideas? My only hunch at the moment is that the VNC Xorg isn't being ran natively and that somehow is causing the issue.

Comment: VNC does not work like X11.  Any reason you cannot just use xterm directly for what you need to do?

Comment: VNC will connect to a VNC server, which it has it own startup script, you can add `xterm` to the same. See this https://almost-a-technocrat.blogspot.in/2010/06/how-to-start-up-vnc-session-with-gnome.html and see if it works for you